# Stuck with sending ng-flow image to Rails server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

So I am trying to use ng-flow to upload images to my Rails server.

Currently I have this html done:

```
<form flow-init
      flow-file-added="!!{png:1,gif:1,jpg:1,jpeg:1}[$file.getExtension()]"
      flow-files-submitted="$flow.upload()"
      ng-controller="MediumNewCtrl" >

    <span class="btn button-xs" flow-btn flow-attrs="{accept: 'image/*'}">Choose file</span>
    <button ng-click="upload($flow.files)" class="button-xs">Upload</button>

    <div class="thumbnail" ng-show="$flow.files.length">
        <img flow-img="$flow.files[0]" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And now if I click the Upload button, then I pass the file to my angular controller which looks like this:

```
angular.module('app').controller "MediumNewCtrl", ($scope, $timeout, $routeParams, $location, $http, $window) ->

    $scope.media = []

    $scope.upload = ($file) ->
        $scope.media = $file[0]
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:    './media' + '.json',
            data:   comment: {image_video: $scope.media, text: "text"}
        }).success( (data) ->
            console.log(data)
        ).error( ->
            # Display error notification
        )
```

But doing this will give me a `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` in my javascript console.

Has anyone else here gotten `ng-flow` to work with Rails successfully? Would appreciate some help with this. They have samples only for php, and it's hard to make anything out of it as it works differently.